# Error 500 jsf.js link in spring webflow + myfaces app

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I develop spring and myfaces app and it produces nonaccessible link to jsf.js.
Generated page contains link which points to dispatcher servlet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/app/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script`>
```

This URL gives error 500:
    /WEB-INF/application/javax.faces.resource/jsf.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

```
viewId=/WEB-INF/application/javax.faces.resource/jsf.xhtml
```

but I found out that working one is  `/myapp/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js`

So, it looks like it produces link to dispatcher servlet, not to faces one, in my web.xml I made following declarations:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value><![CDATA[ 
                     /WEB-INF/config/webmvc-config.xml
                    /WEB-INF/config/webflow-config.xml
                    classpath:view-config.xml ]]>
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using spring 3.2.6 and myfaces 2.2.4 now, but I tried both to upgrade spring and downgrade myfaces with the same result.

Besides ajax functionality application is working - view is rendered and links to other flow pages work as well.

What I am missing? Which configuration options should I check?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out, how to solve it - added spring configuration entry

```
<faces:resources />
```

which fixed problem. It enabled dispatcher servlet to deliver jsf resource.

Comment: HI Michael, Can you please mention specifically where you added this <faces:resources /> ? I am facing similar issue - not able to find the way to fix it.

Comment: @BalusC can you please help me with this ? I am using spring and JSF just like above.